# Can't distribute my Flutter app for iOS in Xcode - "ipa in the package contains an invalid character(s)"

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, flutter, app-store

I get an error when I try to distribute the app to upload it to the App Store:

> App Store Connect Operation Error
>
> The filename _****.ipa in the package contains an invalid character(s).  The valid characters are: A-Z, a-z, 0-9, dash, period, underscore, but the name cannot start with a dash, period, or underscore

I tried:

- flutter clean
- flutter build iOS
- build folder in Xcode
- rebuild in Xcode

But I don't know the reason of this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I have found a solution, editing the display name in Xcode settings of target not enough, you must edit  inside Info.plist file.

Comment: Any other solutions? I have the same problem and renaming the provisioning profile once helped, but the second time I'm trying to upload an app to the Testflight, I have the same problem again

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that there are no restricted symbols in `Bundle name`, `Bundle display` name.

Both of them can be seen in `Info.plist`.

Answer (score 0):

for me its because of invalid character of identifier name in Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles. I changed the identifier name & redownload to the provision file, after that everything will be ok.